# Response not successful: Received status code 404 -- on any api

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, apollo-client

I had been working perfectly on my app and suddenly it started refusing to load all my data.

Even if I change my uri to a public api like: https://countries.trevorblades.com/

I still get this error!

I have a simple app with one component for testing this and nothing works.

```js
//index.js

import { ApolloProvider, ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "'https://countries.trevorblades.com/",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// App.js
import Users from "./components/Users";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Countries />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

//Countries.js
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const GET_COUNTRIES = gql`
  query getCountries {
    countries {
      name
    }
  }
`;

const Countries = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_COUNTRIES);

  if (loading) return <p>... Loading ...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>{error.message}</p>;

  return <>{!loading && !error && <h1>It Should Display this if it works</h1>}</>;
};

export default Countries;
```

Comment: You have a typo in the URL address: `"'https://countries.trevorblades.com/"` - note the single quote after the double quote.